# How to adjust TextBlock MultiBinding to TextBlock & Hyperlink?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I really couldn't find how to resolve the following problem. I have got:

```
<TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource HoverBox}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,5,0" Name="lblAuthFullPath"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="575"                                                     TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="5,0,0,0" 
MouseLeftButtonDown="lblAuthFullPath_MouseLeftButtonDown">
     <TextBlock.Text>
           <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0}{1}{2}">
                  <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxAuthHost" />
                  <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxAuthWebsiteName" />
                  <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxWebServicesAuthentication" />
             </MultiBinding>
     </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

And it works fine.

I want to use `<Hyperlink>` within `<TextBlock>`...

How I can adjust  `<MultiBinding>` to do the same thing for `<Hyperlink>` **instead of** `<TextBlock>`?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hyperlinks` can contain `Runs`, so you might want to apply the binding to the `Text` of a `Run` within the `Hyperlink`

Comment: @DmitryBoyko: I mean you can apply this binding to a `Run.Text`, the `Run` being in the `Hyperlink`

Answer (score -1):

Hyperlink is span and contains of inlines, thus

```
<Hyperlink>
<TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource HoverBox}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,5,0" Name="lblAuthFullPath"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="575"                                                     TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="5,0,0,0" 
MouseLeftButtonDown="lblAuthFullPath_MouseLeftButtonDown">
     <TextBlock.Text>
           <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0}{1}{2}">
                  <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxAuthHost" />
                  <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxAuthWebsiteName" />
                  <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxWebServicesAuthentication" />
             </MultiBinding>
     </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
</Hyperlink>
```

will work.

Comment: `TextBlock` is **not** and inline, this will create a container around the `TextBlock` to host it in the `Hyperlink`, not a very good idea...

Comment: I got this error bu using your solution: Error 5 A value of type 'Hyperlink' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'.

Comment: @H.B. TextBlock is container, but this is not important. This project will have ContentPresenter->TextBlock->Containervisual->Textblock structure. which is perfectly correct. 

Regarding the compilation it compiles, if you'll put Hyperlink not inside Grid for example (Window->Hyperlink->Textblock)

Comment: @Tamir: That would not work either, Hyperlink is an inline, it needs to be used as flow content, e.g. TextBlock->Hyperlink->TextBlock, which is quite the nonsense.

Comment: @H.B. why you consider this as nonsense? This is the way hyperlink works (just in case, you can check and put hyperlink directly inside Window to see. This is kind of span, thus it intended to have another text container (like TextBlock) inside

Comment: @Tamir: Hyperlink has inlines, it is **not** meant to contain containers, if you want Text in a Hyperlink you use a Run.